# Java: ArrayList says index 0 doesn't exist unless I include a String in the parent loop

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, runtime-error

I am in class, and am trying to complete a chapter exercise, but am having some troubling difficulties.

The assignment requests:

> Modify the existing `ArrayList`'s contents, by erasing 200, then inserting 100 and 102 in the shown locations. Use `ArrayList`'s `remove()` and `add()` only. Sample output of below program:
>
> ```
> 100 101 102 103
> ```

Here is the program it provides, with my part included:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayListADT {

 public static void printArray(ArrayList<Integer> numsList, int numOfElem) {
   int i = 0;

   for (i = 0; i < numOfElem; ++i) {
      System.out.print(numsList.get(i));
      System.out.print(" ");
   }

   System.out.println("");
 }

 public static void main (String [] args) {
   ArrayList<Integer> numsList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   int numOfElem = 4;

   numsList.add(new Integer(101));
   numsList.add(new Integer(200));
   numsList.add(new Integer(103));

// I can only access code below this point---------------------------
   int j = 0;
  
   try {
      for (j = 0; j < numOfElem; j++) {
         if (numsList.get(j).equals(200)) {
         numsList.remove(j);

         numsList.add(1, new Integer(102));
         numsList.add(0, new Integer(100));
         }
      
         printArray(numsList, numOfElem);
      }  
   } catch (Exception e) {
      // Catch whatever exception our code is producing
      // Print the error and see what happens.

      System.out.println(e);
   }

// I can only access code above this point---------------------------

    printArray(numsList, numOfElem);

    return;
  }
}
```

When I run this code, the program gives me the right input and passes, but gives me an exception:

```
100 101 102 103

Runtime error (commonly due to an invalid array/vector access, divide by 0, etc.).
```

I've used the good ol power of unit testing to discover that the culprit is:

```
numsList.add(0, new Integer(100));
```

I don't know why! In case it was a syntax error on my part, I tried to switch its position with the other `add()` in the statement block, but it still only reacted to my attempt to `add()` to 0. What did I do wrong? I've tried fixing it with a similar problem's solution and changed `++j` to `j++`, but got no solution from this.

OUTPUT AFTER RUNNING UPDATE 1:

```
✖   Runtime error (commonly due to an invalid array/vector access, divide by 0, etc.).
```

It doesn't seem to like the try/catch.

Comment: What environment is the code being run in? That's not a standard exception message afaik.

Comment: And you wouldn't get a runtime syntax error. Syntax errors should be caught at compile time.

Comment: I copy pasted your code and it ran successfully giving the output `100 101 102 103 `

Comment: In your first loop change ++i to i++

Comment: Also didn't understand why you need a `break label`. A normal break is enough

Comment: @MithunSasidharan why?

Comment: @Carcigenicate It's Zybooks' built in 'textbook' compiler. It's just built into the book 'pages'.

Comment: @MithunSasidharan As stated, this was tried and did not work.

Comment: @JitinKodian I was testing to see if the for() loop was iterating further than I wanted it to.

Comment: @SarahGuarino I think you are overcomplicating the problem. All it's asking you to do is remove the second element directly, and then add two new elements in the correct spot. You don't need to search through the list to find 202. I've posted an answer below which is all you need in the section you're allowed to edit.

Comment: One should never use new Integer(x). Use Integer.valueOf(x) or simply x instead.

Comment: @muzzlator OK, let's say almost never.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need a loop here? You can just directly remove and then add the new elements:

```
numList.remove(1);
numList.add(0, new Integer(100));
numList.add(2, new Integer(102));
```

And you will satisfy your task's requirements

Edit for discussion below:

Put all your code in a `try`/`catch` block (don't worry if you don't know what it is just yet, and see if you get more detailed error messages):

```
try {
     // Put your code here and include the printArray() function
} catch (Exception e) {
     // Catch whatever exception our code is producing
     // Print the error and see what happens.
     System.out.println(e);
}
```

See what the output is and update the question

Comment: Huh, where did you paste it?

Comment: oh i see, I used the word `numList` instead of `numsList` :)

Comment: I'm happy to go over explaining what you saw with you. What string are you referring to?

Comment: I forgot I removed that part... when I add

    System.out.println("Test string");

in between the closing curly brackets of the if loop and the for loop, the error goes away. However, I only get this error when there is no println in between those closing brackets. I left that out for the sake of brevity.

_If numList.add(2, new Integer(102));_ works, why wouldn't _numList.add(0, new Integer(100));_?

Comment: Think your comment got chopped off

Comment: Hm, weird, can you track down more details about the error than whatever error is displayed on your system? I can teach you how if you can't find it

Comment: I'm using a specialized compiler that's built into a web-based textbook, so what access I have to its settings and inner workings is severely limited. If you're familiar with Zybooks, and can give me info that would be amazing!

Comment: I'm going to edit my answer with a suggestion since it will be too hard to type here in a comment.

Comment: Can you move the `printArray` outside of the `for` loop? You'll run into a different issue if it's inside the `for` loop (the array originally has size 3, not 4, so the loop up to `numOfElems` in `printArray` will index outside of the list's size)

Comment: Oh actually, ignore that, I just noticed that printing the exception did nothing anyway

Comment: Well, i'm still a little puzzled. Adding a benign print statement usually only "fixes" rare class of "Heisenbug" errors based on something called "race conditions" which shouldn't apply here. I would like to find out more about the actual error was but looks like they are trying real hard to hide the messy parts of java from you. If that cross symbol was new after adding the `try`/`catch` stuff, maybe you could try my suggestion 2 comments above and instead of `System.out.println(e)`, try `System.out.println(e.toString())` instead.

Comment: Anyway sorry getting close to 3am, i'm going to check this thread in the morning, let me know if you get any closer to finding out why the print statement fixes things. The call to `numsList.add(0, new Integer(100))` should be fine btw, so I would look for something else as the culprit

Answer (score -1):

The for loop does not look like the correct way to do. You can use

```
if ((index = indexOf(new Integer(200))) != -1)
{
    remove(index);
    // add methods..
}
```

Comment: You should elaborate on why you think this will fix the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this doesn't look like code that I recognize, maybe this is more advanced than I've been taught. Is this in another language than Java?

The for() loop is formatted the way my book taught us to, and the for() loop actually works exactly as I designed it to.

Comment: My apologies for poor wordings. The for is also a way to achieve the result. I was just trying suggest that instead of doing iteration we can use the indexOf method to check if the element exists or not.

Comment: Please assign 3 to numOfElem on declaration and increment it by 1 after adding the 102 and 100. I think he printArray throws the error on first call because the arraylist has 3 elements before adding but numOfElem passed to the method is 4.